# Login like Facebook-App

Tags: ios, authentication

I want to login to a webpage via an iOS App. When I start the App for the first time emailadress and password must be entered. After a successful login (Webserver php & msyql), I redirect to the webpage in the App and do the UIWebView. Like Facebook. How can I do it?

Really a beginner in App-development. Any tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Design a UIViewController and has a UIWebView in it. Load web view with the URL request when you need it.

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[webView loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kWebSiteSignUpURL]]];
```

And setting the UIWebViewDelegate to self, so you can implement more logic in each situation.

```
@protocol UIWebViewDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

Comment: Thanks! I am pretty new in Xcode. Where do I have to put the first one and the second one? VieController.m or ViewController.h?